# Exclude directory from tar

Tags: tar, compression

I try to compress my wordpress directory `/srv/www/vhost/wp-intranet`.

But I need to exclude the directory  `/srv/www/vhost/wp-intranet/wp-content/uploads/`

First I changed directory to `/srv/www/vhost/` then I tried it with each one of these commands, but all failed to exclude the directory:

```
tar --exclude="/srv/www/vhost/wp-intranet/wp-content/uploads/" -zcvf wp-intranet.tar.gz wp-intranet/

tar --exclude="./wp-intranet/wp-content/uploads/*" -zcvf wp-intranet.tar.gz wp-intranet/

tar --exclude="./wp-content/uploads/*" -zcvf wp-intranet.tar.gz wp-intranet/
```

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: There is a well thought out answer to this that you can find on this site or by Googling for it.

Comment: I see no difference. You even understood that I meaned directories. For me they are synonyms.

Comment: They are not and your opinion is based on your limited experience. [What is the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078676/what-is-the-difference-between-a-directory-and-a-folder) as the first link you could have easily found but there are far more.

Comment: Since you still understood that I mean directory when I wrote folder, they are.

Comment: I am not the one you need to have understand you. The technical community is the one who will look at you funny. They are the ones you should be concerned about as they are the ones who will decide on your reputation. Improper use of terminology is one deciding factor especially in the face of evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to execute this:

```
tar --exclude="wp-intranet/wp-content/uploads" -zcvf wp-intranet.tar.gz wp-intranet/
```